# Apache not seeing website - CentOS 7

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7, apache2.4

I have setup a lot of Virtual Hosts in Ubuntu but today I needed to do this on a CentOS 7 server. I installed Apache and setup the VHost config but nothing appears when I view the site.

I know that Apache is reading my Config files because if I add a fault in it and restart Apache, it complains about the error.  Is there something "else" that is needed on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this was that the CentOS server had (by default) blocked the HTTP port 80.  This really seems a bit silly but as soon as I allowed the firewall to open these ports for the web traffic, all worked fine:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of virtualhosts are you trying to achieve? name based I guess.

If you are not running on version 2.4> then you need to enable the  name virtual host directive for the IP:PORT pair

NameVirtualHost *:80

The different behavior can depend on the different versions of the Apache servers shipped with the distro.

If not, it could be depending on selinux labels not being set properly. In this case anyway, you would get a permission error. Honestly I don't believe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the settings that I use on a CentOS 7.3.1611 running Apache 2.4.6 I normally use virtualmin / webmin for configuration, but I have looked at the httpd.conf The basic settings that are in my config are

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#502" "#502"
ServerName grid.hosted-systems.co.uk
ServerAlias www.grid.hosted-systems.co.uk
ServerAlias webmail.grid.hosted-systems.co.uk
ServerAlias admin.grid.hosted-systems.co.uk
DocumentRoot /home/grid/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/grid.hosted-systems.co.uk_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/grid.hosted-systems.co.uk_access_log combined
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5

<Directory /home/grid/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All   Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
    FCGIWrapper /home/grid/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/grid/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>

<Directory /home/grid/cgi-bin>
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All   Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.grid.hosted-systems.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://grid.hosted-systems.co.uk:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.grid.hosted-systems.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://grid.hosted-systems.co.uk:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
    php_admin_value engine Off
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
Alias /dav /home/grid/public_html

<Location /dav>
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "grid.hosted-systems.co.uk"
    AuthUserFile /home/grid/etc/dav.digest.passwd
    Require valid-user
    ForceType text/plain
    Satisfy All
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php5
    RewriteEngine off
</Location>

<Files awstats.pl>
    AuthName "grid.hosted-systems.co.uk statistics"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/grid/.awstats-htpasswd
    require valid-user
</Files>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#500" "#500"
ServerName mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk
ServerAlias www.mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk
ServerAlias webmail.mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk
ServerAlias admin.mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk
DocumentRoot /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5

<Directory /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/public_html>
    Options +Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
    FCGIWrapper /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>

<Directory /home/hosted-systems/domains/mirrors.hosted-systems.co.uk/cgi-bin>
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias "/centos" "/home/shared/CentOS"
    <Directory "/home/shared/CentOS">
            Options +Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
            Require all granted
            HeaderName HEADER.html
    </Directory>

Alias "/centos/" "/home/shared/CentOS/"
    <Directory "/home/shared/CentOS/">
            Options +Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
            IndexOptions FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=*
            Require all granted
            HeaderName HEADER.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The settings here set up two virtual websites using port 80 and bound to the same single IP , this is accessable by using http://servername or http://ServerAlias  The DocumentRoot is the location of the files to be servers.
The second VirtualServer is basically the same set up, but it also shows how the Alias section can be used to pull documents from outside the main directory.

As a side note, if anyone spots any vunerabilities in what is posted, let me know or edit and let me know.

Amber-Marie

Answer (score 0):

I try `firewall-cmd --add-service=http` on Centos 7.5 and it work